# Technique to Display Multiple Browser Windows Tiled at Same time?

Tags: browser

I have a separate monitor that I use for Toodledo (a web-based task managment app), in which I like to display various views (Next Action Status, Waiting Status, Planning Status, and Overdue Due-Date items). I've been playing around with some add-ons on Firefox that allow you to split the browser, but they are cumbersome.

I'm now trying Chrome, and opening 4 different browser windows that I've tiled on the screen in quadrants (I use the Compiz grid applet for this). This is not ideal as each browser replicates the URL bar and the tab, and I don't have opening ths windows automated upon restart. Chrome is great in managing screen real estate, but this is not ideal. In Firefox I tried various extension to hide interface elements, but it was very clunky... Am wondering whether anyyone has tried to do similar with TD, and how they achieved what I'm going after?

Am wondering whether someone has a good technique for accomplishing what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Chrome/ium

There are a few Chrome/ium extensions that mimic what you are trying to achieve, but I didn't find any exceptionally good ones.

### Firefox

I did however find a pretty good Firefox extension for screen splitting: **[Fox Splitter](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/fox-splitter-formerly-split-br/)**, it seems to do the job well enough.

### Opera

Opera provides built-in support for managing tabs in this manner. **Right click the Tab Bar**, go to **Arrange** and proceed to select **Tile Vertically**.

### SSB

Alternatively, you could use an SSB (Single Site Browser or Site Specific Browser). An SSB is an application with an embedded browser designed to work exclusively with a single web application. It doesn't have the menus, toolbars and accoutrements of a normal web browser. You would then use one of these per web page and tile them using the Compiz grid plugin. You could use **[Mozilla Prism](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/prism)**, an SSB that uses Firefox as its back-end. Chrome/ium also provide SSB functionality, this is done by first navigating to the desired web page, then clicking the **Wrench Icon > Tools > "Create Application Shortcuts..."**.

Note: My original answer contained more hyperlinks, but I was prevented from posting because I do not have enough reputation.

Comment: I forgot about SSB, but I agree that this is the way to go with Compiz grid... just tried it out and it works well, without breaking my ability to just run plain old normal browser session with regular interface elements... Chrome will be the ticket for me. Can you think of a way or launching 4 x SSB with one click? The SSBs instance on Chrome seem to remember their screen position.

Comment: You'll probably need a custom script to open them all at once and get them arranged in a grid using Compiz.

Answer (score 1):

If the toolbar and tab are the problem, why don't you get rid of both? This can be done in Views > Toolbars.

If you open another window *from* there and want your toolbar back, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> will bring you back to the Views dropdown, whence you can add the toolbars back.